# Cosmos DB Query documents with timestamp nearest to now

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection of Appointments.  I need to be able to query appointments that are nearest to now.

Is that possible in Document DB / Cosmos DB?

My initial thought was to use ABS and Order by, so something like this

```
SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY ABS(c.ScheduledTime - 1509562136)
```

Where 1509562136 is "now", however Cosmos doesn't like that expression in the order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you have to perform progressive queries like

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ScheduledTime BETWEEN 1509562136 - 60 AND 1509562136 + 60
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ScheduledTime BETWEEN 1509562136 - 120 AND 1509562136 + 120
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ScheduledTime BETWEEN 1509562136 - 240 AND 1509562136 + 240
...
```

And then sort the results of the query locally until you've found the closest appointments. See https://github.com/arramac/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/Spatial/NearestNeighbor/Spatial/SpatialHelper.cs for a very similar implementation, but for geospatial queries.

Because Cosmos DB is designed for low memory footprint (for scale), order by queries are only served from the index. Therefore it does not permit sorting on expressions.